# Mockito is not recognized by Android (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito

Here is my class test:

```
private const val FAKE_STRING = "APP NAME"

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class UnitTestSample {
    @Mock
    private lateinit var mockContext: Context

    @Test
    fun readStringFromContext_LocalizedString() {
        // Given a mocked Context injected into the object under test...
        `when`(mockContext.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .thenReturn(FAKE_STRING)
        val myObjectUnderTest = ClassUnderTest(mockContext)

        // ...when the string is returned from the object under test...
        val result: String = myObjectUnderTest.getHelloWorldString()

        // ...then the result should be the expected one.
        assertThat(result, `is`(FAKE_STRING))
    }
}
```

Here is a piece of my gradle.build.kt (Kotlin DSL):

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    kotlin("android")
    kotlin("kapt")
    kotlin("android.extensions")
    id("com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin")
    jacoco
    maven
}

dependencies {
        ...
        //Test base
        testImplementation("junit:junit:4.12")
        testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.3")
        testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.0.3")
        androidTestImplementation("androidx.test:runner:1.2.0")
        androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0")

        //Unit Tests
        testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-core:3.0.0")
        testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-inline:3.0.0") //support for kotlin final classes

        //Android UI Test
        androidTestImplementation("org.robolectric:robolectric:3.7.1")
}
```

As you can see, Android Studio doesn't reognize Mockito. I've already imported `org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner`

[image: mockito not recognized]

I'm running this sample unit test under

```
src/test/java/.../UnitTestSample.kt
```

Do you have any idea on how to make it work?

**Edit (Solution):**

I finally made it work with some help of the comments section. The problem was **caused by "maven" plugin import** on plugins section, and I didn't see that because the base project I downloaded to convert my Gradle to DSL Kotlin had those plugins working. Somehow this was causing Mockito not to be available at compile time, as @MartinZeitler stated. According to @second, "Maven's runtime does not translate to gradle's runtimeOnly but instead compile".

Comment: You are missing `import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner`. It could be because of other errors in the file that the auto-resolve isn't working. Or your gradle dependencies may be missing something.

Comment: @dharms I've imported it but it doesn't recognize but mockito is red in import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner

Comment: Do you use JUnit 4 or 5 - seems your imports are a mix of both? If its 5 you might want to try the extension instead.

Comment: @second I use JUnit 5, JUnit 4 import was only to test a few things. When I setup Jacoco, it asked me for a TestEngine to run coverage tests, so I imported JUnit 5 one. But I think there's no problem at all. I can either remove it or use JUnit Vintage (which allows retrocompatibility on JUnit 4 and 3) meanwhile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear: `an annotation argument must be a compile time argument`.

Replace `testImplementation` with:

```
debugImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-android:3.2.4"
debugImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-inline:3.2.4"
```

Comment: @second `@RunWith` is the annotation and `MockitoJUnitRunner` the argument; for some reason not both are available at compile time, as it is supposed to be.

Comment: @MartinZeitler that was the problem! I figured it out looking into the plugins with help from you guys

Comment: @DimasMendes Found out that only `debugImplementation` works, after finding my own answer again.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit**: Cleaned up the answer

---

For JUnit5 and mockito use the following dependencies (or newer) and scopes:

```
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.4.2")
    compile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.4.2")
    testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-core:3.0.0")
    testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:3.0.0")
    testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-inline:3.0.0")
```

In your test use the Extension instead of the Runner (which is for JUnit 4).

`@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension::class)`

---

When running with the JUnit 5 dependencies of 5.0.3, I got the following error, so consider upgrading to a newer version (as shown in the dependencies above).

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
org.junit.platform.commons.support.AnnotationSupport.findAnnotation(Ljava/util/Optional;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/util/Optional;
...
Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension.afterEach(MockitoExtension.java:214)
```

---

For the maven to gradle conversion I used this site
https://sagioto.github.io/maven2gradle/

Comment: this link merely repeats what I've wrote... when not working with Android DSL, but defaulting to Java.

Comment: @second I added both `testImplementation ("org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:3.0.0")`  and `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension::class)` and removed dependency for JUnit 4. But now it tells me `Unsolved reference: MockitoExtension::class`

Comment: @second I finally got it!!! on my plugins section, I had 'maven' added (I don't know why), and that was causing the error. I will add details to the end of my answer

Comment: Actually I just figured out that maven's `runtime` does not translate to gradle's `runtimeOnly` but instead `compile`. So `Martin Zeitler` might have been correct about that part.

Comment: Yes I had this insight because all of you and your comments. Thank you guys!

Comment: I cleaned up my answer, no point leaving the tries & errors there ;)